# PostgreSQL 9.5 - change to max_connections not being visible to slaves

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've added a pgbouncer process to my master server so I want to lower the number of connections from 1500 down to 100 or so to free up resources on the master, but when I change it on both the master and slave, the new setting isn't visible to the slave:

```
2020-01-29 14:59:19 dbr5 postgres[47563]: [4-1] 2020-01-29 14:59:19 EST [47563]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 100 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 1500)
```

This is after the master has been changed:

```
master=# show max_connections;
 max_connections
-----------------
 100
(1 row)
```

Any clues why the slaves aren't taking the new setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slave needs to know the master's `max_connections` setting to perform this check, and so the master notifies the slave of changes via a WAL entry.

However, the slave won't read any WAL entries if its current `max_connections` setting is incompatible with the **last known** setting on the master.

You should reconfigure the master first, give the corresponding WAL entry a chance to replicate, and then reconfigure the slave.

Comment: Putting in `hot_standby = off` on the slaves, restarting the master, and then switching it back worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Putting in `hot_standby = off` on the slaves, restarting the master with the new lower connection number, and then after confirming the slave had received the change by looking in the log for the `FATAL:  the database system is starting up` log entry, then switching it back to `on` worked.  The system now has the new lower connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration parameters, when set globally, are never replicated. They can be set

- in `postgresql.conf`
- with `ALTER SYSTEM`
- with command line options when the server process is started

The last option clearly cannot be replicated, and the first two use configuration files which are also not replicated.

This is a feature: you may want configuration parameters different in some cases (although it is not generally commendable).

You will have to change the parameter on the standby server.