# Google Cloud SQL FATAL: hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 100 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 500)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

I was running PostgresSQL 13.4 replica instance on Google Cloud SQL. The replica keeps failing to start after maintenance with the error `FATAL: hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 100 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 500)` even though `max_connections = 500` flag which is same as primary instance is explicitly set.

I found this post [PostgreSQL 9.5 - change to max_connections not being visible to slaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974871/postgresql-9-5-change-to-max-connections-not-being-visible-to-slaves) but `hot_standby` flag is not modifiable in Cloud SQL.

Restarting and stopping replication does not work so far.

Comment: With PostgreSQL, changing the setting on the standby and restarting it would fix the problem. If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to ask Google what they changed here.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you. I have tried to fix hot_standby flag but it's not allowed in Cloud SQL. I'll ask google and report back here if I could find the solution.

Comment: I got an answer from google. The cause was because I was running my instance with minimum machine type (db-f1-micro) and low memory size. When the instance restarts from maintenance, the instance read the default max_connections (100) and fails to start due to the mismatch of the flag value from primary instance. The workaround I got from google is to use larger machine types.